# Need to keep duplicates and delete all unique lines

Tags: regex, compare, notepad++

I have two large text files
Looking for something that compares the two files for lines containing the same string and deleting all the rest. Hope that makes sense.

Example:

list1.txt

```
number1:1010:1020:1030
number2:1010:1020:1030
number3:1010:1020:1030
number4:1010:1020:1040
```

list 2.txt

```
number1
number2
number3
number100
```

output=

```
number1:1010:1020:1030
number2:1010:1020:1030
number3:1010:1020:1030
```

Anything that can do this? I would really appreciate help, thank you.

Comment: Very vague question. All your lines are unqiue (because of the `numberX:` in the beginning of each line).

Comment: Also, this is definitely not something you should do with a regex.

Comment: Sorry, looking for anything that can do this. A program would be nice. Sorry for the vague question, looking for something that compares the two files for lines containing the same string and deleting all the rest. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I think what we are confused about is that list1.txt and list2.txt do not have any lines in common. Even though they both contain the string "number1", the first file contains text after that on the same line and the second file does not have any extra text.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the vague question. I am looking for something that takes the strings from txt1 and compares them with txt2. Then keeps all lines that contain strings from txt1 and deletes everything else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to sketch what you should program.

1. Read `file1.txt` into a `List<String>` line by line.
2. Same for `file2.txt`.
3. Loop over the lines of file 1, and check if the line `.contains()` any of the lines you read in file 2. (By nesting another loop).
4. If it does contain something of file 2, immediately go to the next line of file 1 (by `continue`-ing the outer loop). If it does not, then delete that element from the list (don't forget to decrease the loop variable, as you deleted the item at the current index).